# Set default parameter to some rspec requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

###### Context:

Some of our rails routes need a locale to generate url (for instance `domain.com/en/courses`) while the base controller (for `domain.com`) doesn't use locale.
We set it up by adding the locale in the `default_url_options` of the right controller.

###### Problem:

But when testing it in Rspec, I get a `missing required keys` error asking for the locale.
When I add a locale param in the spec like so `visit course_path(@course, locale: :en)` everything is back to normal... but we have a LOT of specs !

###### First attempts:

I tried using the `default_url_option` method in `ActionView::TestCase::TestController` and `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` like so

```rb
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.default_locale }
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.default_locale }
  end
end
```

But it set the locale for the whole app, not just some specific routes...

###### Question:

Is there a way to set a default parameter for **some** routes in rspec support ?

Comment: Is there a namespace, convention, or tag that you plan on applying to distinguish those routes that you need a default parameter on? That could impact strategy used.

Comment: @stringsn88keys , yes: for clarity I simplified the routes, but all localized routes are in the same 'dashboard` namespace, so it's actually `domain.com/en/dashboard/courses` for instance

Comment: how about stub `default_url_options` to return `{ locale: locale_you_want}` on test cases which will be test for `some routes` , so it's only effected on those test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## First solution

on ApplicationController

```
if Rails.env.test?
  before_action :set_default_locale

  private
  def set_default_locale
    I18n.locale = params.fetch(:locale, :en)
  end
end
```

i know that it's not the correct way

it doesn't update your app on rspec level, but so far this is what I can think on my head

---

## Second alternative solution

Update on route level

```
if Rails.env.test?
  defaults = { locale: :en }
else
  defaults = {}
end
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|id/, :defaults => defaults do
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the problem occurs even before that: when trying to generate the `course_path(@course)` in the `visit` line of the spec, it needs the locale then...

Comment: This is still present in Rails 7.1 and unclear how to set up correctly. It seems to me that the underlying problem sits on the border of RSpec and Rails and neither side documents the interplay very nice.